# Can i update a signed jar using an ANT Task?

Tags: ant, jar, java-web-start, signing

Hi I am trying to deploy an application using webstart. I have a requirement to update a  jar which is signed before i actually deploy( basically to update the IP/Port info). I am trying to use ANT to update the jar. Is there are way to achive this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't speak specifically to ANT or to JAR files.  But generally speaking, one of the purposes of signing is to prevent tampering with the code.  Once the code has been modified, the signature is no longer valid and this is by design.  You'd have to re-sign the JAR file after making the updates.